# A set of rationals with rationals lower bounds but with no rational greatest lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a set of rationals that has rational lower bounds, but no rational greatest lower bound. I was thinking of the set $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x > \pi \} $. Does this set work ?

Comment: Does this set work? ans : just find the glb no? :)  note that glb is unique

Comment: $\inf S = \pi $ but im stuck on proving this

Comment: Are you having trouble showing there are rationals greater than, but arbitrarily close to, $\pi$?

Comment: I dont understand your question, but I want to know if my example is correct, but i am unable to show $\inf S = \pi $

Comment: Proving that $\inf S=\pi$ is almost free. Just show that any lower bound must be at most $\pi$. Suppose $g$ is a lower bound for $S$ and $g>\pi$. Then $g>(g+\pi)/2>\pi$ and $(g+\pi)/2\in S$ thus $g$ is not a lower bound giving us a contradiction. This means any lower bound $g\leq \pi$ but $\pi$ is obviously a lower bound so it's a glb. Your issue now is that there can't exist a rational glb. You might use some density argument for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that your set $S$ has no glb on $\mathbb{Q}$  we need two facts:

1) If a glb exists tha it is unique.

2) $\pi$ is an irrational number.

Then, as suggested in the comment of DRF, you can see that any lower bound $g$ od $S$ must be $g\le \pi$ and, since $\pi$ is a lower bound, it is the greatest and, from 1) it is the unique glb, and, from 2) it is not $\in \mathbb{Q}$.

So, what is your truble?

1) is simple to prove by contraddiction: if $d\ne e$ are two glb, suppose $d<e$, than $e$ is not a lower bound (by definition of glb) and we have the contraddiction.

2) is more difficult to prove. You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)

If you want a set for which it is easiest to prove that the glb is not rational, you can use $U=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}: x^2>2\}$, in this case the classical [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality) that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational is easy.

Comment: So we can say that $1$ is a lower bound of U. Then $\sqrt 2 $ is the inf(U) because it is **not** a rational number.